# How to estimate the price of a European call when the underlying is not tradable?

Tags: options

Assume you have a vanilla call on an underlying $S$ with strike price $K$ and expiry at time $T$.

Let's say that $S$ follows a [GBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) with volatility $\sigma$.

In general, one would use the Black-Scholes [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model) to price this option, but this relies on many assumptions and in particular that one can buy/sell the stock in continuous time.

What if we cannot trade the stock (for example, we're not allowed to). What are the different ways of valuing this options?

The only way I see is to estimate your own utility function given an expected payoff and a volatility, which is really hard, but I wanted to know if there was any other well-known approach?

Comment: If the asset is non-tradable, isn't this worthless? So the price of the option should be zero?

Comment: @StudentT I've heard this argument, but let's say the payoff is cash-settled, then it clearly has a value right?

Comment: Is there a liquid market for these options? You could calibrate your favorite option model to this market.

Comment: @Olaf I see your point. I'm trying to consider a case where the options are not traded either.

Comment: Did you have a look at weather derivatives?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Try *real options valuation* methods if *underlying* is not *tradable*, and use the volatility of a *proxy / peer or comparable* asset as an estimate. None of the approaches would be *perfect* with unlisted stocks (in general), so you'll surely end up in using own judgement to gauge the *fair value* of the option under study.

Here is an interesting [link](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/pdfiles/execval/optval.pdf).

2 -  Alternatively, I would have valued this company using *DCF methods* to get an e*xpected firm value*, then *expected price*. Once *expected S* is known, use *volatility of the firm peers*, then plug those info to the BS formula. Otherwise in case of **IPO**, use e*stimated share price from brokers*, as it might be quicker than valuing the firm by your own

3 - Finally (*might be least favourable*), *use numerical methods* (like *trinomial trees*, etc.) if you're stuck with the *maths* as you seem to have mentioned in the initial post. Although you're dealing European options, as long as nodes get bigger prices from tree and BS methods do converge (*undeniable fact*). Once again: use *estimated share price* (from brokers in case of *IPOs* or use own company valuation *via* *DCF methods*, *Multiples*...) and *volatility* (from peers / industry..) to work out the payoffs up to the end, before discounting them back.

Comment: Well a real option would be valued assuming you delta hedge in most cases, I'm looking to see which other methods are available.

Comment: @SRKX: could you be a bit more specific in providing us with the nature of the non-tradable asset, since there exists a profusion of `alternative asset classes` (non-traded)? and the methods could be more or less suited depending on type you're dealing with.

Comment: @StudentT:  The option price should not be `0` in any case (just because underlying is `non-traded`).

Comment: @owner example is a call on a company not publicly traded, which might become tradable in the future